# [Pycharm 2018.2.4]-[Tensorflow 1.12.0]-[Protobuf 3.6.0] ERROR

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm not English so I apologize in advance for any errors caused by the translator. I'm using Pycharm 2018.2.4 64bit and i have installed Tensorflow 1.12.0 or 1.11 (i don't know) and this installation has installed a protobuf 3.6.0. I show you this information below in the images below:

[Protobuf Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lzFs.png)

[Tensorflow Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDfFC.png)

I'm using python 3.6 as an interpreter and this can be seen in the tensorflow version photo. The scripts I'm running are sure to be correct as they are 100% executable on another pc but it is Win7. I now find myself on Win10. The problem is that I'm trying to solve a problem that I would like to help from the stack overflow community. While I will wait for answers I will try to check the versions on the win7 pc to compare them with those of win10. Now I show you what I print the console when I try to start the process

```
C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/root/PycharmProjects/DeepNeuralNetwork/DDoS.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/root/PycharmProjects/DeepNeuralNetwork/DDoS.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 46, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.
```

Doing various Internet searches I came across a small variation of the protobuf that should be moved from 3.6.1 to 3.6.0 (which is already present)

Comment: solved the problem, I went in preference and in the settings of the interpreter I realized that the version of protobuf was 3.6.1 and in the drop-down menu I entered the 3.6.0 and everything worked properly.

Comment: how you Installed tensorflow ?? using pip or pip3. if you are using python 3.6, install it using pip3